# with sns.axes_style(): causes the plot to not display Chinese characters

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm able to plot figure with Chinese labels with code below:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['SimHei']  # used to display Chinese labels normally
revenue = ["133", "111", "1145"]
depense = ["13", "56", "66"]
date = ["7月10日", "7月11日", "7月12日"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(date, revenue, label="收益")
ax.plot(date, depense, label="支出")
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Out:

[image]

I found that after I added `with sns.axes_style("whitegrid"):` and `sns.set_style('whitegrid', {'font.sans-serif': ['SimHei']})`, Chinese characters in the figure turn into squares:

```
sns.set_style('whitegrid', {'font.sans-serif': ['SimHei']})

with sns.axes_style("whitegrid"):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(date, revenue, label="收益")
    ax.plot(date, depense, label="支出")
    ax.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Out:

[image]

Does someone could help to deal with this issues? Thanks.

PS: to display all available fonts in Windows, we can use:

```
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontManager
mpl_fonts = set(f.name for f in FontManager().ttflist)
print('all font list get from matplotlib.font_manager:')
for f in sorted(mpl_fonts):
    print('\t' + f)
```

Comment: `sns.set_style` changes a lot besides the font. https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set_style.html

Answer (score 2):

I think you can run `sns.set_style('whitegrid', {'font.sans-serif': ['SimHei']})` once and delete it. Then run it again and the typesetting will reserve and you can handle the font after like using `mpl.rcParams['axes.unicode_minus'] = False # 解决保存图像是负号'-'显示为方块的问题`

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean by adding `import matplotlib as mpl; mpl.rcParams['axes.unicode_minus'] = False`? I tested, it seems not working.